# C# queue multiply all items by -1

Tags: c#, queue

What is an elegant (short) way to multiply each item of a queue by -1 (queue.ForEach does not seem to exist) and it seems to be excessive to read to entire queue and to write it to another queue. Is there a way to do it in-place?

Comment: `queue.ForEach` would be a readonly method and wouldn't do what you want anyway. (just like `foreach`)

Comment: Hmm, no that's -100 points for using the wrong collection object.  Very hard to get that above 0 when you don't explain why you think you need to do this.

Comment: Agree with @HansPassant, you're probably using the wrong collection. What you'd be doing is wasteful and you identified why it would be.....

Comment: You don't have to write to another queue; you can write to the same queue. But you still have to call both `Enqueue` and `Dequeue` on each item.

Comment: Queues are FIFO only. If you want to alter the data in a queue use a list not a queue. Queues should only be used where you want an actual queue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Editorial aside: I don't see why this question is downvoted or voted to close. It's a perfectly reasonable question.

If all you want to do is obtain the elements in a queue negated:

```
var negated = myQueue.Select(x => -x);
foreach(int x in negated) ...
```

Note that "negated" will continue to work even if you change the contents of the queue! The query object is evaluated when enumerated, not when created.

Note that `myQueue` is not changed at all; `negated` is simply a wrapper around it that negates the elements as they are enumerated.

Answer (score 2):

[Queues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) are designed so that an item can only either be written to the back of the queue (enqueue) or read from the front of the queue (peek/dequeue). Changing an item in the middle of the queue is simply not a defined operation. So even if a `ForEach` method existed, it would tend to defeat the purpose of the data structure.

It would be better to negate the items as you queue or dequeue them. You could write an extension method if you really wanted to, for example:

```
public static class QueueExtensions
{
    public static int DequeueAndNegate(this Queue<int> queue) 
    {
        return queue.Dequeue() * -1;
    }

    // -- or --

    public static void NegateAndEnqueue(this Queue<int> queue, int value) 
    {
        queue.Enqueue(value * -1);
    }
}


var queue = new Queue<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
while (queue.Count > 0) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(queue.DequeueAndNegate()); // -1 -2 -3
}
```

If you really need a data structure that allows in-place modification of items, you need to use a different data structure, e.g. a `List<int>`.